# Is it possible to stream screen of an Android phone if you have adb access?

Tags: android, adb, recovery

I just got my screen destroyed and can't see anything on the phone, and I need access to the phone quickly.

Since the screen is completely black I can't see anything but I use it for local Android development so adb and all the developer settings are enabled.

Is it possible for me to stream Android screen to my laptop and somehow recover my accounts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use scrcpy to mirror your screen: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

Comment: A requirement is that the computer you're accessing from has debugging enabled, and is authorized. To make sure that works in the future, back up your ADB keys (on Linux they're in ~/.android).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer of davehenry. You can also use this tool https://www.vysor.io/

Comment: thanks will try both, scrcpy seems to fail to install both via brew and manual build on mac... i'll try with windows

Comment: You can try Vysor. It is easy to install there is Windows ,MAC,Linux and Browser base available : https://www.vysor.io/download/?return=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vysor.io%2F

Comment: tried unfortunately i'm required to confirm it on the phone, i guess i'm out of luck, still the software probably does the job